# borderless form edge

Tags: c#, forms, border

I want to make a borderless form that has a thin black edge (like the first one from the picture http://www.vcskicks.com/remove-titlebar.php ). I want to do this because the form is poorly visible(it combines with my background).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Make a borderless form as described in the article you linked to
- Add a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) control
- Set the panel's Dock to "fill"
- Change the [BorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.borderstyle.aspx) on the panel to get the effect you want. ([BorderStyle.FixedSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.borderstyle.aspx))
- Add the remaining controls to the Panel.

Answer (score 1):

- Change the Form's padding to 1,1,1,1
- Set the Form's backcolor to the color you want for your border
- Add a panel
- Set Panel to fill the form
- Set Panel color to 'control' or whatever